# Converting circle to rounded rect background of TextView

Tags: android, background, drawable

I am working with view where it will work like a badge and suppose there is 1 letter it will use the circle and as the text grows it will start to become the rounded rectangle.

Answer (score 0):

use ConstraintLayout layout parameter to keep the aspect ratio

app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"